# Change color of select box according to chosen option?

Tags: html, css

I have this code:
When I select "0" the text in the dropdown box also gets red.
But when I select "1" the text is black. 
Now I want the text to be "green" in the dropdown box if I select "1".

```css
.mySelect {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.mySelect option {
  color: green;
}

.mySelect option[value=""] {
  color: red;
}

.mySelect:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<select class="mySelect" required>
  <option value="">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g3wmsc8k/

Comment: You need to define the default color for the .mySelect class.

Answer (score 2):

Add color `.mySelect`

```
.mySelect { font-size: 2em; color:green }
.mySelect option { color: green; }
.mySelect option[value=""] { color: red; }
.mySelect:invalid { color: red; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/arLn7vtz/

Comment: Thank you! And if I want a third option in the dropdown box. For exmaple "2" and that should be blue? Also when selected.

Answer (score 1):

Green should be the default color of both `select` ans `option`.

The red color should be for `:invalid` `select` and `option` without `value`.

```css
.mySelect {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.mySelect,
.mySelect option {
  color: green;
}

.mySelect:invalid,
.mySelect option[value=""] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<select class="mySelect" required>
  <option value="">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
```

If you need more than to different values to choose from, you need a JS solution like this one:

```js
"use strict";
console.clear();

;
(function(id) {

  document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    var options = e.target.options
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = options[options.selectedIndex].value
    e.target.style.color = options[options.selectedIndex].dataset.color ? options[options.selectedIndex].dataset.color : 'white'
  })
})('colors');
```

```css
select,
option {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}

option[value="red"] {
  background-color: red;
}

option[value="blue"] {
  background-color: blue;
}

option[value="green"] {
  background-color: green;
}

option[value="pink"] {
  background-color: pink;
  color: black;
}

option[value="gold"] {
  background-color: gold;
  color: black;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<select name="color" id="colors">
  <option value="red" data-color="white">Red alert</option>
  <option value="blue" data-color="white">Blue tech</option>
  <option value="green" data-color="white">Eco-Green</option>
  <option value="pink" data-color="black">Pink lady</option>
  <option value="gold" data-color="black">Gold Finger</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you! And if I want a third option in the dropdown box. For exmaple "2" and that should be blue? Also when selected

Comment: @ThyLe That would only be possible with the help of JavaScript. You cannot set the  CSS values according to the child options particular values. At least not with current CSS. Future CSS Layer 3 may have a `:has()` rule, which could do this, but it's not finished yet

Comment: Do you know how to do it? Or do you have an example?

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why, but it's not working in my project